# How to find Shapiro-Wilk using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find shapiro wilk test for data frames.

About shapiro wilk
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.shapiro.html

**Data frame 1:**

```
Stationid
       10
       11
       12
       13
       14
       15
       16
       17
```

**Data frame 2:**

```
Stationid  Maintanance
       10           55
       15           38
       21          100
       10           56
       22          101
       15           39
       10           56
```

I need to shapiro wilk for station id's in dataframe 1 on dataframe 2

**Expected Output**

```
Stationid   W           P 
       10  0.515        55.666667
       15  0.555        38.500000
```

Note: W,p given in the table is not correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with cast output to `Series` for new columns:

```
#check if numeric
print (df2['Maintanance'].dtypes)
int64

from scipy.stats import shapiro

df3 = df2[df2['Stationid'].isin(df1['Stationid'])]

df = (df3.groupby('Stationid')
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(shapiro(x), index=['W','P']))
         .reset_index())
print (df)
   Stationid         W         P
0         10  0.689908  0.004831
1         15  0.747003  0.036196
```

EDIT:

```
data = ['abc15','acv1','acv2','acv3','acv4','abc18','acv5','acv6'] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Stationid']) 
print (df1)
  Stationid
0     abc15
1      acv1
2      acv2
3      acv3
4      acv4
5     abc18
6      acv5
7      acv6

data1=[['abc15',55],['abc18',38],['ark',100],['abc15',56],['ark',101],['abc19',39],['abc15',56]] 
df2=pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Stationid','Maintanance']) 
print(df2) 
  Stationid  Maintanance
0     abc15           55
1     abc18           38
2       ark          100
3     abc15           56
4       ark          101
5     abc19           39
6     abc15           56
```

Problem is `shapiro` [cannot working if number of values is less as 3](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/685#issuecomment-130551274), so added filtering for data with length `>2`:

```
from scipy.stats import shapiro
df3 = df2[df2['Stationid'].isin(df1['Stationid'])]
print (df3)
  Stationid  Maintanance
0     abc15           55
1     abc18           38 < group with length 1 (abc18)
3     abc15           56
6     abc15           56

df = (df3.groupby('Stationid')
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(shapiro(x), index=['W','P']) if len(x) > 2 
                          else pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan], index=['W','P']))
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  Stationid     W         P
0     abc15  0.75 -0.000001
1     abc18   NaN       NaN
```

Or filter out this groups:

```
from scipy.stats import shapiro
df3 = df2[df2['Stationid'].isin(df1['Stationid'])]
print (df3)
  Stationid  Maintanance
0     abc15           55
1     abc18           38
3     abc15           56
6     abc15           56

df3 = df3[df3.groupby('Stationid')['Stationid'].transform('size') > 2]
print (df3)
  Stationid  Maintanance
0     abc15           55
3     abc15           56
6     abc15           56

df = (df3.groupby('Stationid')[['Maintanance']]
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(shapiro(x), index=['W','P']))
         .reset_index())
print (df)
  Stationid     W         P
0     abc15  0.75 -0.000001
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178396/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-how-to-find-shapiro-wilk-using-python-pandas).

Answer (score 1):

There must be a cleaner way, but this does the job:

```
import pandas as pd

from scipy import stats


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Stationid': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Stationid': [10, 15, 21, 10, 22, 15, 10],
                    'Maintanance': [55, 38, 100, 56, 101, 39, 56]})

df2['Maintanance'] = df2['Maintanance'].astype(int)

df = df1.merge(df2, on='Stationid', how='inner').groupby('Stationid').apply(stats.shapiro).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'shapiro'})

df = df.join(df['shapiro'].apply(lambda val: pd.Series(val, index=['W', 'P'])))

df[['Stationid', 'W', 'P']]
#   Stationid         W         P
#0         10  0.689908  0.004831
#1         15  0.747003  0.036196
```

Comment: Will check and tell

Comment: @YogeshSP Can you confirm that your numbers are integers. See my definition of dataframes in edit.

Comment: Small correction Station Id in my real data is object and Maintanance is float. Please help me.

Comment: @YogeshSP Please see the edit. The part with `astype(int)`.

Comment: Yeah done I have changed my dataframe types now : StationId: Object Maintainace int64 and still shows the error

Comment: import pandas as pd
data = ['abc15','acv1','acv2','acv3','acv4','abc18','acv5','acv6']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Stationid'])
print (df1)

data1=[['abc15',55],['abc18',38],['ark',100],['abc15',56],['ark',101],['abc19',39],['abc15',56]]
df2=pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Stationid','Maintanance'])
print(df2)

Comment: This is my dataset could you please check it